# R. Finding summary statistics grouped by subset in R

Tags: r

I have a huge data set in R. Each observation has a categorical label to it and a numerical value in this case a mass.

I’m looking to find summary statistics (Mean, Median, Mode) for my mass values grouped by each subset label I have.

I’m completely stumped so any help would be appreciated.

A snippet of the data is

```
Order_or_higher First_appearance_mya Last_appearance_mya    Mass_kg

Rodentia    -13.9   -11.3   0.006665867
Rodentia    -11.8   -7.5    0.005259311
Rodentia    -14.4   -14.4   0.036379302
Rodentia    -16.7   -13.7   0.056373546
Rodentia    -14.1   -14.1   0.008149854
Rodentia    -28.4   -20.3   0.009393331
Rodentia    -2.4    -2.4    0.02126367
Rodentia    -0.9    0   0.014909521
Rodentia    -3.8    -3.7    0.027798999
Rodentia    -2.8    -0.5    0.01889694
Rodentia    -1.6    -1.6    0.017115766
Carnivora   -5.8    -5.7    63.51300709
Carnivora   -17.4   -14.5   281.8132792
Carnivora   -20.1   -15.5   130.4832311
```

With many many more categorical values

Comment: We can't really help you at all unless you provide a clear example of data

Comment: Done, added the data

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways, you can do this in R. Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. But first, take note that the function `mode()` in R does not return your *mode estimate*. To learn more about the `mode()` function, type `?mode` in your console. So we have to create a function that returns the mode. Obviously, we can start with the `table()` function because it returns the frequency distribution of `x` in `table(x)`.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  uniqx <- unique(x)
  uniqx[which.max(table(x))]
}
```

Let's now apply this new function and the existing built-in functions in R.

```
tt <- "Rodentia -13.9 -11.3 0.006665867 
Rodentia -11.8 -7.5 0.005259311 
Rodentia -14.4 -14.4 0.036379302 
Rodentia -16.7 -13.7 0.056373546 
Rodentia -14.1 -14.1 0.008149854 
Rodentia -28.4 -20.3 0.009393331 
Rodentia -2.4 -2.4 0.02126367 
Rodentia -0.9 0 0.014909521 
Rodentia -3.8 -3.7 0.027798999 
Rodentia -2.8 -0.5 0.01889694 
Rodentia -1.6 -1.6 0.017115766 
Carnivora -5.8 -5.7 63.51300709 
Carnivora -17.4 -14.5 281.8132792 
Carnivora -20.1 -15.5 130.4832311"

df <- read.table(text = tt, header = F)


library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(V2:V4), funs(mean, median, Mode))
```

And here is the output:

```
#   V1      V2_mean V3_mean V4_mean V2_median V3_median V4_median V2_Mode V3_Mode V4_Mode
#   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Carniv…   -14.4  -11.9  1.59e+2     -17.4    -14.5   130.       -5.80   -5.70 6.35e+1
# 2 Rodent…   -10.1   -8.14 2.02e-2     -11.8     -7.50    0.0171  -13.9   -11.3  6.67e-3
```

Answer (score 1):

The dplyr package has these functions and is designed for these tasks.

Assume that `d` is your dataset.

```
d %>%
group_by(<subset>) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(<mass>),
          median = median(<mass>),
          mode = ModeFunction(<mass>))
```

Where you'd define a function to declare `ModeFunction`. hpesoj626's function works well and simply.

Comment: What are %>% means to be?

Comment: @DanielV, the function `mode` does not return the statistical mode estimate. :)

Comment: @SomebodyNeedingHelp the %>% function is called the 'pipe function'. It passes the result of the previous function onto the next function as the first argument of it.